# Show uniqueness of interpolation constructed with sum of exponentials

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, interpolation, interpolation-theory

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

> Given $x_0,\ldots,x_n$ distinct real points. Choose a function $$P_n(x)=\sum_{j=0}^n c_j e^{jx}$$ s.t. $$P_n(x_i)=y_i \qquad i=0,\ldots,n $$ Show there's a unique choice of $c_0,\ldots,c_n$. Note that you can reduce this to polynomial interpolation.

To attack this, I was just thinking to write Taylor series for the exponential:

$e^{jx} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(jx)^k}{k!}$

So the conditions become: $$\sum_j c_j \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(jx_i)^k}{k!}=y_i$$ for $i=0,\ldots,n$. The issue I see is that the poly has an "infinite" degree, so I don't know how to move from here. Any hint is highly appreciated!

Comment: For smooth non-polynomial functions, I would recommend using the Wronskian test to show linear independence.

Comment: Alternatively, to reduce to polynomial interpolation, use the transformed variable $x_i' = e^{x_i}$ and the fact that the exponential is injective.

Comment: @Doug I see, so I have $P_N(x)=c_j t^j$, being $t=e^{x}$. But why do I need that to be injective?

Comment: Suppose that you started with the exponentials and did polynomial interpolation to find polynomial $Q(e^x) = P(x)$.  But, if for each $z$, there were two $x_1,x_2$ with $z = e^{x_1} = e^{x_1}$, then there would be at least two different sets of $n$ points giving you the same function $P$, which is not possible if $P$ itself has dimension $n$.  We could say that the sets $\{x_i\}$ and $\{e^{x_i}\}$ are isomorphic.

Comment: In the last line, you mean *degree*, instead of dimension, right? @Doug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x_0, \cdots, x_n$ are distinct points, the Vandermonde matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 &x_0 & x_0^2& \cdots & x_0^n\\
1 &x_1 & x_1^2 & \cdots &x_1^n\\
\vdots & \vdots& \vdots&\ddots& \vdots\\
1& x_n & x_n^2 & \cdots & x_n^n
\end{pmatrix}
$$
is invertible. This is equivalent to say that the interpolating polynomial is unique. In your case, the set of conditions $P_n(x_i)=y_i$ leads to a linear system having the matrix

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 &e^{x_0} & e^{2x_0}& \cdots & e^{nx_0}\\
1 &e^{x_1} & e^{2x_1} & \cdots &e^{nx_1}\\
\vdots & \vdots& \vdots&\ddots& \vdots\\
1& e^{x_n} & e^{2x_n} & \cdots & e^{nx_n}
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 &e^{x_0} & (e^{x_0})^2& \cdots & (e^{x_0})^n\\
1 &e^{x_1} & (e^{x_1})^2 & \cdots &(e^{x_1})^n\\
\vdots & \vdots& \vdots&\ddots& \vdots\\
1& e^{x_n} & (e^{x_n})^2 & \cdots & (e^{x_n})^n
\end{pmatrix}
.$$This matrix is still invertible because $e^{x_0}, e^{x_1}, \cdots, e^{x_n}$ are distinct numbers.